# Slick slider или как фиксить баг свойства centerMode?

Tags: javascript, html, slider, slick.js

Доброго времени суток!
Есть некоторые баги `slick-слайдера`, возможно кто-то стыкался или подскажет как это обойти. Как всё обустроено:
Делаю слайдер с фиксированой шириною `445px каждый элемент` и `центральный слайд 600px`, то есть всего показывается `3 слайда` (6 всего).
Но есть один мелкий баг со свойством `tranform` при прокрутке, слайд дергается: [codepen.io - тык](https://codepen.io/seeecond/pen/NyqEMy)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/740522/slick-carousel-%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8

Comment: @fanfer Странно, искал - не нашел. Плохо искал =Р  
Спасибо, сейчас отпишусь, если получится!

Comment: @fanfer я не могу словить padding при ширине 445px + center: 600px. Не получается..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно попробовать такой, обходной, вариант
Суть в том, что все слайды одинаковый ширины. А работать с внутренними контейнерами

```
.rc2 .slick-slide {
  width: 520px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.rc2 .slick-slide .rc2__item {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: orange;
  height: 80px;
}
.rc2 .slick-active .rc2__item {
  width: 440px;
}
.rc2 .slick-center {
  background-color: red;
}
.rc2 .slick-center .rc2__item {
  width: auto;
  margin: 0 -80px;
}
.rc2 .slick-center + .slick-slide .rc2__item {
  float: right;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RQPELM

Comment: Это я уже и сделал)
С отрицательными марджинами
Но этот slick так просто не сдается.. посмотри внимательно на последний слайд и клацни на следующий, он обрезает клас и снова добавляет его... я уже не знаю, что делать.. плюнуть дизайнеру в лицо или оставить всё как есть :)