# Подергивание в slick slider при переключении слайдов с изменением ширины

Tags: html, css, jquery, slick.js

При использовании `centerMode`, `variableWidth` и изменении размеров слайдов при переключении, некорректно рассчитывается смещение по оси x, сначала уходит на 80-90px в сторону смещения слайда, а потом выравнивает по центру.
Подобная проблема была в [этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/740522/slick-carousel-%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8), но там все решилось уменьшением падинга для увеличиваемого блока, чтобы сравнять ширину. В моем случае подобных вещей не сделать, т.к. меняется ширина сразу у нескольких слайдов и у каждого она разная.

P.S.
В маленьком превью слайдер почему-то не работает, нужно сначала нажать "Развернуть фрагмент", а затем "Выполнить код".

```js
$(function(){
  $('.year-slider').on('init', function(event, slick){
    var $currentSlideEl = $(slick.$slides.get(slick.currentSlide)),
        $prevSlides = $currentSlideEl.prevAll(),
        $nextSlides = $currentSlideEl.nextAll();

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        $prevSlides.eq(i).addClass('sibling-' + (i + 1));
        $nextSlides.eq(i).addClass('sibling-' + (i + 1));
    }
  });

  $('.year-slider').slick({
      infinite: false,
      slidesToShow: 1,
      centerMode: true,
      centerPadding: '0px',
      variableWidth: true,
      focusOnSelect: true,
      waitForAnimate: false,
      rows: 0,
      responsive: [
          {
              breakpoint: 768,
              settings: "unslick"
          }
      ]
  });

  $('.year-slider').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
      $('.year-slider__item').removeClass('sibling-1 sibling-2 sibling-3 sibling-4 sibling-5');

      var $currentSlideEl = $(slick.$slides.get(nextSlide)),
          $prevSlides = $currentSlideEl.prevAll(),
          $nextSlides = $currentSlideEl.nextAll();

      for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
          $prevSlides.eq(i).addClass('sibling-' + (i + 1));
          $nextSlides.eq(i).addClass('sibling-' + (i + 1));
      }
  });
});
```

```css
.year-slider {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 60px auto;
}

.year-slider__item {
    width: 30px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 94px;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 0.47px;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.year-slider__item:hover {
    color: #000 !important;
}

.year-slider__item + .year-slider__item {
    margin-left: 30px;
}

.year-slider__item.slick-current {
    width: 140px;
    font-size: 60px;
    color: #000;
}

.year-slider__item.sibling-1 {
    width: 90px;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.year-slider__item.sibling-2 {
    width: 70px;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.year-slider__item.sibling-3 {
    width: 50px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.year-slider__item.sibling-4 {
    width: 30px;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.year-slider__item.sibling-5 {
    width: 30px;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="year-slider">
    <div class="year-slider__item">1980</div>
    <div class="year-slider__item">1981</div>
    <div class="year-slider__item">1982</div>
    <div class="year-slider__item">1983</div>
    <div class="year-slider__item">1984</div>
    <div class="year-slider__item">1985</div>
    <div class="year-slider__item">1986</div>
    <div class="year-slider__item">1987</div>
    <div class="year-slider__item">1988</div>
    <div class="year-slider__item">1989</div>
    <div class="year-slider__item">1990</div>
    <div class="year-slider__item">1991</div>
    <div class="year-slider__item">1992</div>
    <div class="year-slider__item">1993</div>
</div>
```